# 64 bit Java less scalable than 32 bit Java on Solaris

Tags: java, jetty, solaris, load-testing

Folks, last week during a loadtest workshop of a Java server application at a big customer site, we were able to run only around 1300-1800 concurrent sessions when using a 64 bit JVM while with the same configuration we were able to run 2800 concurrent session with a 32 bit JVM.

Environment information:
Solaris 10 , Java 1.6.0_30 , Jetty 8.1.5 , Web application is I/O bound with 1000's of mostly idle threads per process , 6-12 Java processes were spawned with little difference , Memory 16GB wasn't full at the time of failure , CPU capacity was less than 50% , file descriptors were set to 65536.

When running with the 64 bit JVM at some point we reached a state were CPU was less than 50%, plenty of memory both at the machine level and Java process level was still available.
At this point we started getting "IOException" and "EOFException" at various layers of the product. As far as we could tell there was no real network or communication problem at this time. It seems as if the Solaris machine was running out of some resource related to socket communication and it looks like the 64 bit JVM consumes twice as much of this resource compared to a 32 but JVM.

Any ideas ?
One notable difference is that 64 bit JVM consumes 1024k per thread stack while the 32 bit consumes only 512k per thread. Could this be the reason ?
Is thread stack and socket I/O allocated from the same memory pool on Solaris ?
Can this pool be increased ?
Should we try to reduce the thread stack size on the 64 bit VM to 512k ?

Comment: For a fair comparison I would use the latest version of Java 6 ie update 45 as many bugs and performance tweats were done after update 30. Ideally you should use the latest version of the OS with Java 7 update 25.

Comment: The thread stack size only use virtual memory ie it is a maximum and doesn't use real memory unless actually needed.

Comment: I'll clarify my question, what should be my next test with 64 bit VM ?

Comment: I'll clarify my question again, what should be my next test with 64 bit VM ? My thinking is that (1) we should upgrade to Java 1.6.0_45 and install all related Solaris Hotfixes, if this won't help (2) Use -Xss512k to reduce thread stack allocation and use -XX:+UseCompressedOops flag. What I still don't understand is why the scalability limitation is reflected as an IOException ?

Comment: Usually an IOException comes with a messages.  Can you see what the message is?  BTW `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` should be the default with Java 6 update 21+

Comment: At some point we start losing sessions getting: java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
It looks as if something is causing the sockets to close.

Comment: We also get org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException but without stack trace

Comment: And java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out - all pretty much as the same time

Comment: This would suggest your machine is so overloaded, that it take too long to receive a packet.  This can be the case even if only a fraction of your CPUs are being used. i.e. your cpus don't appear to be all 100% busy.  Why this is the case for 64-bit but not 32-bit is unclear.

Comment: How do you define / measure memory in "Memory 16GB wasn't full at the time of failure" and what kind of hardware is it ?

Comment: We have memory and CPU measurements in place using top. This is a Solaris 10 machine with 8 x 1.6 GHZ CPU.

Comment: For now the customer decided to use 32 bit JVM for this specific project. I'm planing to reproduce this 64 problem again in our labs but this is only planned for October. I'll post my results then.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that stacks contain mostly pointers or pointer-sized primitives.  In 64-bit they are double the size than in 32-bit.  So, for the same stack "depth" you need double the bytes.  1024K is the equivalent to your previous setting.  Don't change it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try adding the `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` option (compress ordinary object pointers) to the JVM and see how your test compare.

This option which might not yet be the default with the JVM version you use compensates the negative effect of 64 bit pointer size while keeping the overall 64 bit virtual memory space advantage.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is that the limitation we run into is as follows: 
(1) The server processes total memory allocation grows beyond the size of the physical memory of the server machine --> 
(2) The Solaris server starts swapping memory pages to disk --> 
(3) Because of the swapping, Java garbage collection becomes very slow (the swapping is so bad that sometimes it takes more than 300 seconds for a single collection !) --> 
(4) When using socket communication some processes are waiting for I/O while others are stuck in garbage collection --> 
(5) We get socket timeout and EOF exceptions in unexpected places since the process performing GC does not answer requests from other processes. 
(6) We do not get OutOfMemory errors since technically the Solaris still has memory available in its swap file and the Java maximum heap size has not been exceeded.

Therefore my conclusions are as follows: 
(1) The reason that the 32 bit JVM scales better than the 64 bit JVM is that 64 bit requires 50% or more memory compared 32 bit, therefore the 64 bit JVM allocates all available physical memory under smaller load compared to the 32 bit one. 
(2) The key to running 4000 concurrent sessions on the given Solaris server is to reduce memory consumption and/or increase the available physical memory. 
(3) In order to scale better you need the 32 bit JVM to be able to spawn more threads, by default, it can only spawn give or take 3000 threads per process and this is not enough for my specific use case.

Configuration changes: 
(1) Add the following command line flags to monitor garbage collection -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
(2) Reduce the thread stack size to -Xss384k this allows for running more threads per processes and reduces the memory allocation of a process. The default stack size on Solaris in 32 bit is 512k and in 64 bit 1024k.
(3) Monitor memory consumption during the loadtest using the prstat and vmstat commands and make sure there is no excessive swapping.
(4) Do not allocate more than -mx800m per 32 bit Java process to conserve memory and speed up garbage collection, if necessary spawn more processes but make sure you do not fill the physical memory.